# Xamarin.Forms: Is there an event to indicate that Custom Renderer has executed?

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I'm trying to address a shortcoming in an open source Xamarin.Forms control which uses custom renderers.

The issue is that I can only set certain properties on the control **after** the custom renderer has run. I'm just not sure when that would be. Is there any lifecycle event in a control or the page which would indicate that all custom renderers have executed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xxxRenderer class exposes the **OnElementChanged** method, which is called when the Xamarin.Forms control is created to render the corresponding native control. This method takes an `ElementChangedEventArgs` parameter that contains `OldElement` and `NewElement` properties. These properties represent the Xamarin.Forms element that the renderer was attached to, and the Xamarin.Forms element that the renderer is attached to .

```
protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
  base.OnElementChanged (e);

  if (Control != null) {
     // custom renderers have executed here

  }
}
```

The call to the base class's **OnElementChanged** method instantiates a native control(or view) , with a reference to the control being assigned to the renderer's Control property.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don't "own" the renderer itself. I'd really like to avoid forking the source code to put in customizations, if at all possible.  Is there any point in the Xamarin.Forms project when I would know that the custom renderer has executed?

Comment: We could not konw that if the custom renderer has executed in forms . If you don't want to "fork the source code to put in customizations",why did you use custom renderers any more ? We use it because we want to do some special things in specific platforms.

Comment: If you do want to know , you can use messagingCenter . And send notification in `OnElementChanged` and subscribe it in forms.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems MessagingCenter will also not work.  The file I'm looking at is https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad/blob/master/src/SignaturePad.Forms.Platform.Shared/SignaturePadCanvasRenderer.cs   OnElementChanged begins on __line 50__, and it immediately calls the base.OnElementChanged, which fires the  event. But what I need is to know some point after __line 89__ has executed. Without that line, I cannot set the Strokes for the SignaturePad from Xamarin Forms.

Comment: I don't think you can implement it if you could not edit the Renderer.

Comment: I see.  Thank you for your help though!